# Airflow task retry not done

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, airflow

I have a production environtment with an `Airflow webserver/scheduler` running in a `docker` instance on `AWS`.

I am using AWS Blue/Green deployment to achieve an always working service.

When I do a new deploy through `AWS Codepipeline` the `AWS B/G` raises a new `docker` instance in the `EC2`, and then drop the old one. When this is done the tasks that were runnning fails.

I understant that is due to the connection between `scheduler` and `webserver`, but despite having `retry=2` it only fails and the restart is not done. On the other hand, when the task fails due some bug, then it retries fine.

My dags params are:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'I',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 1),
    'email': [' '],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15),
    'on_failure_callback': slack_alert
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess a solution for your deployment would be the following:

1. Stop the scheduler on blue deployement to avoid that new tasks get scheduled
2. Wait until all tasks/DAGs were finished or kill the tasks
3. Continue the deployement of green

You may also use [`execution_timeout`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#package-contents) which also should mark the tasks after a certain time as failed:

> **execution_timeout (datetime.timedelta)** – max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.

Comment: thanks @PhilippJohannis.

I will investigate in how to do that